# Preventing SocketIO Not To Create Namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, namespaces

I have a question about dynamic namespaces in socket.io.

I implemented a dynamic namespace with regex in socket.io and when a client want to join to namespace I want to be sure that if the client has authorization to join this namespace or not.

To handle this I added a middleware for dynamic namespaces to authorize client.

Here is the problem; in first time(namespace did not created yet) when a client want to join namespace(client does not have authorization), the namespace is created automatically by socket.io

Here is what I need; I do not want that socket.io creates namespace if the client has no authorization for namespace.

I search for that but I could not find anything about that.

Does socket.io has ability to handle this requirement?

Thank you very much